# Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, dpkg, gnome-terminal

I was updating my linux mint 18.3 to linux mint 19.
The error I get is `Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory`.
Then I Restarted my System, after that I can't open the terminal.
I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to run command line and fixing the `LC_ALL` error by using the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` and `sudo aptitude install locales` and it worked.
Then I tried to install terminal by using the command `apt install gnome-terminal` but it gives the error

```
Setting up install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 5: /etc/environment: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to resolve that using this https://askubuntu.com/a/920076/842467 but nothing happened.

Comment: According to the error message, you have an unterminated quoted string in your `/etc/environment` file. Did you look at that?

Comment: My `/etc/environment` file looks like this `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171"`

Comment: The `:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171/bin"` bit looks out of place.  Please add the contents of `/etc/environment` to the question so that we can see what it actually looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about error messages is that they tell you what's wrong.

Your error message clearly says that there is an unterminated quoted string in `/etc/environment`. Once you read that, you should investigate that file to see if it looks odd with regards to double quotes.

[In a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453782/syntax-error-unterminated-quoted-string#comment824496_453782), you mention that your `/etc/environment` file has the contents:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games" :/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171"
```

(or something similar, formatting is difficult in comments).

Here, you can clearly see that the `:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171/bin"` bit at the end of the first line looks out of place (and a space too many).

You, or a script, have edited the file and messed up the `PATH`. That line now contains an unbalanced double quote.

My guess is that the `PATH` should be set as:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171/bin"
```

Comment: I have changed  `JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171"` to`JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171/java"` and `PATH`

Comment: @UjjwalSingh Since I'm not a Java user, I can't say whether that is correct or not.